# How to stop TinyMce from converting image url into <img>?

Tags: images, tinymce, embed, plugin-tinymce

My TinyMCE Editor automatically turns image URLs into an embedded image. How can I deactivate this behavior and just display the URL instead?

Comment: wrap it in code or pre tags instead perhaps? eg. <code>URL</code> or <pre>URL</pre>

Comment: I don't want to fix it by hand because the editor is used in a forum in the frontend. I need to disable this behavior completely.